# What is the "correct" volume for averaging the microscopic electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

In our introductory solid state lectures we were told that macroscopic electric field that we use in Maxwell equations is averaged out over the atomic distances to smoothen the drastic variations of electric field, like it blows up at nuclear positions.

But clearly, this averaging procedure is dependent over the volume we decide to integrate over—for insatnce, I could average over the *entire* volume yielding me a constant electric field over that entire volume.

So what decides the volume over which one should do this averaging?

Answer (score 1):

As with everything in physics, it depends on what we actually measure. Specifically in this case, that means it depends on the length scale at which we are able (or choose) to probe the system with electromagnetic fields. Quoting from Zangwill's *Modern Electrodynamics*

> No single averaging scheme applies to every physical situation and the desired resolution scale typically differs from problem to problem.

Averaging over atomic distance scales makes sense for studying solid-state or other condensed matter, because typically at most we are concerned with the structure of such matter at molecular or atomic scales, i.e., crystalline structure or molecular correlations. Variations in the charge density or fields at subatomic scales are less important for the macroscopic behavior of such systems.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.